# Насколько безопасна выборка из базы?

Tags: php, mysql

В коде движка нашел подобный код (и не в одном месте)

```
$delete_name=str_replace("'","",$_GET['delete_name']);
$query="select count(*) from catalog_data where name='".$delete_name."'";
$kol = query_count($query);
```

т.е по-сути, перед отправкой в базу, только замена одинарной кавычки. Насколько безопасна данная выборка будет, если нет никакой фильтрации или pdo ?

Желательно развернутый ответ, если небезопасно ! Спасибо

Comment: И кстати, почему вам так хочется использовать устаревшие способы работы, поддержка которых уже прекращена и они понемногу начинают исчезать с хостингов. И привязка переменных не только делает код безопасным, так как заведомо исключает любые подстановки, но и более коротким (не надо применять escape в любых видах) и его выполнение в БД может быть на 50% быстрее за счет того, что СУБД не надо строить заново план выполнения и можно воспользоваться кешем планов. А подстановка переменных начисто убивает возможность использования кеша

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Строго говоря, MySQL требует только, чтобы обратная косая черта `\` и
>   символ кавычки `'`, используемый, используемый для указания строки в
>   запросе, были экранированы.
>
> Функция [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) экранирует другие символы, чтобы
>   облегчить их чтение в файлах журнала.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255585/what-does-the-x1a-characters-mean/#16255607

Экранирование слэша нужно чтобы при экранировании кавычки нельзя было экранировать сам добавляемый слэш. В вашем примере делается не экранирование кавычки, а удаление, значит со слэшем делать ничего не надо и инъекция SQL кода невозможна.

Тем не менее можно как минимум вызвать отказ в обслуживании, передав обратную косую и заэкранировать последнюю одинарную кавычку

Comment: Плюс к этому я видел одну атаку, которая вызвав простую синтаксическую ошибку в запросе, приводила к записи информации об этом, включая часть запроса не в тот лог файл, который к несчастью имел расширение php и было возможно потом выполнить этот лог, положив нужный php код в качестве сообщения об ошибке !

Comment: @Mike согласен, дополнил

Comment: точно подметили, ошибка синтаксиса произошла и записалась в log.ms .  Подскажите, почему именно данный формат файла  выбран, если есть какие-то предположения  ?

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian может не формат, а расширение? Где тот файл лежит у вас?

Comment: да, расширение имел в виду. Лежит в папках (Logs) сайтах и с сайтом не взаимодействует, в браузере сразу качается , не открываясь . 
Запрет к нему поставил на всякий случай